# pip3: Command Not Found on OS X

Tags: python, macos, unix, pip, pythonpath

While installing python packages, I am getting error as:

```
mquadri$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

Path to bin `/usr/local/bin` is present in `$PATH`:

> mquadri$ echo $PATH
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:**/usr/local/bin**:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Content of `/usr/local/bin`:

```
mquadri-ltm:PaiWeb mquadri$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/
total 47416
# ... some packages
-rwxr-xr-x    1 mquadri  admin       281 Nov 25 00:27 pip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 mquadri  admin       283 Nov 25 00:27 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 mquadri  admin       287 Nov 25 00:27 pip2.7
lrwxrwxr-x    1 mquadri  admin        66 Aug 18 16:23 pip3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3
lrwxrwxr-x    1 mquadri  admin        68 Aug 18 16:23 pip3.4 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3.4
# ... some more packages
```

On checking the folder pointed by the symlink to `pip3` and `pip3.4`. i.e.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/
```

these are missing from there. **Any possible what might would have caused that?** (Earlier it use to work, though haven't used from long time)

Comment: Re-installing the `python` (was using version 3.4.4) worked. But I am intrested in knowing the possible cause of it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not have python3 installed at all anymore?

Try just reinstalling python3, it comes with its own version of pip3 so you should be good after that. If it thinks python is stored in /Library/Frameworks then it means you probably installed it via some sort of installer instead of something like homebrew.

Comment: It is installed. In fact my project based on python3 is working perfectly fine. I installed it by downloading it from the official site very long back and at that time it used to work. Later something happend, and I am not sure when. Also, I don't have any trace of any such incident in my history

Comment: Can you run `python pip`? You could also try removing the entries for Python 3.4 in your path, if your python version is 3.5 then you don't want conflicts by running 3.4 binaries. Run `python --version` in your project directory to check which version is active.

Comment: Yes, `python pip` works fine. Also, I re-installed the package and now I am able to access `pip3`. But I am intrested it knowing what might be the cause of this issue

Comment: My best guess here is you upgraded from Python 3.4 to Python 3.5 and somewhere along the way, pip3 was incorrectly removed as part of the upgrade? Not really something that can be diagnosed remotely without direct access.

Comment: Earlier it was version 3.5 and then actually I downgraded it to 3.4. But at that time it use to work fine. Anyway thanks for the help :)